# Retrieve all fields using while in Joomla

Tags: joomla-3.x, database

I'm trying to retrieve data using while and it won't work. 
The page just keeps loading and ends up with a blank page; no errors or anything but, when i use foreach, it works.

Any explanation?

The code i'm using doesn't work

```
 while($row=$this->functionname){
    echo $row['fieldname'];
  }
```

when i use this one below, it works.

```
foreach($this->functionname as $row) {
   echo $row['fieldname']
}
```

I have tried placing in diferent files but i have the same result.

Comment: Please include some code to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: The while statement doesn't iterate through $this->functionname. It's like saying while($i=1) {...}. It's always true and you get an infinite loop.

Comment: Oh sure. Thank you Robbie.